# $n$th derivative of $\sin^3x$

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

How do I find the general formula for the $n$th derivative of $\sin^3x$ ?

I tried to differentiate $4$ times, but I couldn't find a pattern for $n$ in general.

I used Leibniz's formula for the $n$th derivative, but I couldn't simplify that to a general formula. I would like some hints or a better way to find the $n$th derivative for functions.

Comment: There is indeed a generalization, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faà_di_Bruno%27s_formula.

Comment: Thank you, that's very helpful.))

Answer (score 11, accepted):

$(\sin\, x)^{3}=\frac 3 4 \sin \,x -\frac 1 4 \sin(3x)$ which makes the computation trivial.

Answer (score 0):

I’ve just written about the the $k$th derivative of the $n$th power of $\sin$ (and $\cos$ and $\sinh$ and $\cosh$).

[On the derivatives of the powers of trigonometric and hyperbolic sine and cosine](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1911.01386.pdf).

There’s the expression using the complex definitions and the binomial rule:

$$\frac{\partial^k}{\partial x^k}\left[\sin^n x\right]$$
$$= \frac{(-1)^n}{2^n}
\cdot \sum_{r = 0}^n (-1)^r \cdot \binom{n}{r} \cdot (2 r - n)^k \cdot \left[\cos\bigl(\dfrac{(k - n) \pi}{2} + (2 r - n) x\bigr) + i\sin\bigl(\dfrac{(k - n) \pi}{2} + (2 r - n) x\bigr)\right].$$

But the expressions using polynomials are perhaps less obvious, and appeal more to my sense of mathematical beauty.